# How to change a component style once it is mounted?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

While I know how to [dynamically bind styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) I did not find a way to change the style of an element once it is mounted.

As an example, for the component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <another-component></another-component>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .class-defined-in-another-component {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

is it possible to change `color` to `red` in `<style>`?

Note: I am specifically interested in modifying the style and not using a construction such as `<span :class="{color: dynamicColor}">`, where `dynamicColor` would be a `computed` value. This is because this modified style will actually be [applied to downstream components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204121/903011) (`<another-component>` in the example above).

Comment: What you try to achieve is to modify the CSS at runtime. Have a look here at some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998993/change-css-rule-at-runtime. Vue.JS itself does not provide any special functionality for this.

Comment: You can have two CSS classes and just change them. What you are trying to do is not possible. It would mean chaning your code.